# MySQL 2013 (CR_SERVER_LOST) Error

Tags: mysql

I'm facing an extremely weird issue right now. I have this very simple query that is being run from an application using the MySQL C Connector:

```
SELECT `sid` FROM `students` WHERE `name`='Bren' LIMIT 1
```

This query works fine when run from phpMyAdmin, however when run from the application it will sometimes fail with the following error:

```
Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I have absolutely no idea what could cause such query to fail. It worked just fine in previous versions of my software and now it doesn't. I am linking to the exact same MySQL library (libmysql.lib), and I haven't changed my database wrapper code. My MySQL settings have also never changed. It's also worth noting this error occurs instantly after the query is executed, so this can't be due to any kind of timeout. Since the previous version works just fine without any error, I believe there is something I must have changed that is causing this but I don't know what it could be, since DB code hasn't changed.
How would I go about solving this? I'm running out of ideas...

Comment: I really don't think it has to do with any kind of timeout because as I mentioned, it occurs right after the query is executed.

Comment: Have you tried going through [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html)?

Comment: Yes, and as you can see none of this helps my case. Neither do most SO threads I've read over the past few days. They mostly refer to timeouts, etc, except my query is on a table with about 30 rows and there is no delay issue.

Comment: Looks more like a networking related issue.